Is there a way to figure out the behavior of hailstone sequence with binary representation?
I'm a university student and posting this question while studying $3n+1$ conjecture.
Recurrence relation of sequence is as follows:
$$ a_{n+1} = \begin{Bmatrix} \frac{a_n}{2},&  \text{if }a_n \text{ is even} \\ \frac{3a_n+1}{2}, & \text{if } a_n \text{ is odd} \end{Bmatrix}$$
Define $ b_n := \lfloor \frac{a_n}{2} \rfloor$ . if $b_n$ is odd, $a_{n+1}$ also odd. also if $b_n$ is even, $a_{n+1}$ also even.
by recurrence relation of $a_n$, I got $ b_{n+1} = \lfloor \frac{b_n}{2} \rfloor + (b_n +1)(a_n\mod2) \rfloor $
Putting it all together, I got $ b_{n+2} = \lfloor \frac{b_{n+1}}{2} \rfloor + \left (  b_{n+1} + 1 \right ) \left ( b_n - 2 \lfloor \frac{b_n}{2}\rfloor \right ) $
Is there a way to figure out the behavior of such sequence? (I think it wouldn't have been such problem if there had been)
I expected  that binary representation for the initial terms of the sequence would be helpful, But this gets complicated quickly.

Might be of interest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Using floor, we can also write $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}2+(2a_n+1)\left(\frac{a_n}2-\left\lfloor\frac{a_n}2\right\rfloor\right)$$ $$=a_n(a_n+1)-(2a_n+1)\left\lfloor\frac{a_n}2\right\rfloor$$
